# Convert a numpy array to generate a image

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have a tensorflow prediction results which is of type tuple.

```
np_pred_boxes == (1024, 1, 4)
np_pred_boxes == <type 'tuple'>
```

Now, I want to convert this array into to a image object.I use np.asarray to convert the tensorflow predicted box of type tuple to numpy array but get the below error.

```
np_pred_boxes = np.asarray(np_pred_boxes)
print 'type == ', type(np_pred_boxes)
img = Image.fromarray(np.asarray(np_pred_boxes))
img.save('/Users/prem/Downloads/tf_image.png')
```

Error:-

```
  File "/Users/em/Documents//crop_image.py", line 91, in <module>
    img = Image.fromarray(np.asarray(np_pred_boxes))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2361, in fromarray
    raise TypeError("Cannot handle this data type")
```

Comment: If you have a bug, avoid nested function calls. Use intermediate variables instead.

Comment: You wrote `np_pred_boxes = np.asarray(np_pred_boxes)`; now what is `np_pred_boxes.dtype`?  (It would be easier to discuss your code if you didn't reuse variable names like that.)

Comment: What color model does the tuple represent? Here is a list of the ones PIL supports: http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/handbook/concepts.html#modes

Comment: @Warrendtype is float 32.

Comment: Thanks.  I assume `np_pred_boxes.shape` is something like (m, n, 3) or (m, n, 4).  Is that correct?

Comment: (1024, 1, 4) is the shape

Comment: So the first bit of "code" that you show should actually be `np_pred_boxes.shape == (1024, 1, 4)`.  As it is now, it looks like `np_pred_boxes` *is* the tuple (1024, 1, 4).

Comment: Pillow will interpret the shape (1024, 1, 4) as an RGBA image with just one column of pixels.  Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [the modes supported by Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/handbook/concepts.html#modes).  The only floating point mode is for grayscale images (mode `'F'`).  You'll have to either convert your array to 8-bit integers, or give the `mode` argument to `fromarray` and let Pillow do the conversion to 8-bit integers for you.  For example,

```
img = Image.fromarray(np_pred_boxes, mode='RGBA')
```

Be sure to verify that that does what you want.  You could check by converting `img` back to an array and inspecting the 8-bit values.  E.g.

```
a = np.array(img)
print(a)
```